# activateTargetDocument()

Tags: vba, ms-word

I believe I may have mistakenly overwrote the macros for activateTargetDocument().
Is there a way to find the relevant code for replacement?
I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Document.Activate.
This was the closest I could get to the macros.

Please assist,

Thank you

Comment: Document.Activate makes a particular document object the active document in Word. I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi @CharlesKenyon, I mistakenly saved a macros I copied online with the activateTargetDocument() macros name. I am new to using macros and so I am speaking out of little experience. I am wondering if there is any place where I can get the original code for the activateTargetDocument() macros. I hope that makes some sense. Thank you.

Comment: You will need to find your original. There is no generic activateTargetDocument macro or command.

Comment: There is no generic 'activateTargetDocument()' macro. Moreover, without knowing exactly what that macro does/did, it would be impossible for anyone to recreate. I suggest you reload the original from your backups. You do make backups, don't you?